# What will happen if we use two sitemap - sitemap.xml & sitemap_index.xml

Tags: sitemap

I have two site map on my website- sitemap.xml & sitemap_index.xml. Is there any disadvantage of having it? Does it will effect the website? Should i redirect to one sitemap? Which is best suitable format for the sitemap?

Comment: You can create a [sitemap index](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/75712?hl=en) to let search engines know about multiple sitemaps.

Comment: Thank you for the response @Dencker
I want to ask one more thing.
Will having two sitemap harm the website? Which sitemap will google give preference?